# Where is the error handling in StripeCheckout.open?

Tags: stripe-payments

I use the following code successfully to create a charge token:

```
StripeCheckout.open({
  key: 'pk_test_99999999999999999',
  amount: 2000,
  name: 'XYZ',
  description: 'Your Order',
  panelLabel: 'Pay Now',
  token: function(res) { 
    //do something with the token, but where is the error handling?
  }
});
```

Am I missing something? Where's the error handling if a customer enters an invalid card or something? Or will a charge token always be generated, and the errors will only show up when you actually create the charge on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a closed callback that can be called if checkout is closed, but the only time checkout will close itself is if a token is generated. Since you're passing amount, Checkout will do an $0/$1 authorization on the card to ensure its validity, though the card could still decline when you attempt to charge it server-side.

Comment: Yeah. But that's it right? I'm guessing that generating the token can't, uh, error. Ever?

Comment: Stripe checkout would abstract any errors, the token function would only be called with a token

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to programming. What exactly do you mean by 'abstracting errors'?

Comment: In software abstraction is basically the idea that there are different layers of software, and higher level layers hide the implementation and difficulties of the lower levels. So with checkout, you don't deal with the errors of "the card number is not valid, or they entered an expiration date in the past, etc" since its handled by a piece of tech that happens at a lower level